# Change timeout of an entry of ipset with iptables rule

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ipset, netfilter

I'm trying to create a set with `ipset` and using it in some `iptables` rules.
`ipset` has **timeout** option to set a countdown timeout to an entry of a set to automatically remove it after a period of time. here is an example:

```
#create a set with default timeout, zero means no timeout
ipset create myset_down iphash counters timeout 0
#add an ip to the set with 60 seconds timeout
ipset add myset_down 192.168.56.101 timeout 60
#iptables rule
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set myset_up src -j ACCEPT
```

In the above example the ip `192.168.56.101` automatically removed from set `myset_down` after *60* seconds. but I wan idle timeout, it means if no packet received from ip `192.168.56.101`  for 60 seconds, then the ip must removed form the set. Maybe could write an `iptables` rule to create this capability, but I don't know how!

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: Iptables has two powerful modules "**recent**", "**hashlimit**" using which you can address your requirements.